# $timeout not working when set data from outside scope of angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and using the following piece of code to set databinding to the view.

Metadata is a global variable which is set from outside angular scope asynchronously.

I am using $timeout to check if the Metadata is available or not.

If i set the timeout interval from 1 to 100, without any looping, the view refreshed with data.

But in my case, the data takes some time to load, so i set this looping logic to check and this scenario the view not getting refreshed with data.

Appreciate any help.

Note:
   Not in a position to use $http, since the UI framework we are using has some restriction.

```js
 var app = angular.module('MetaDataApp', []);
    app.controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {
        $scope.MD = {};
        var loaddata = function () {
            if (Metadata == null || Metadata == undefined) {
                console.log('no data');
                $timeout(loaddata, 100);
            }
            else {
                console.log('data available');
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.MD = Metadata;
                });
            }
        }
        $timeout(loaddata, 100);
    });
```

Comment: post your html code please.

Comment: If `Metadata` hasn't been defined yet, the following check `if (Metadata == null ...` will give `ReferenceError: Metadata is not defined`. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: note: you don't have to use `$apply` inside `$timeout`, all the code inside is being wrapped by `$apply` automatically

Comment: Hi tasseKATT, i dont see any error on console. when i try the follow, i can see the value set on matiMD after sometime..               $scope.$watch('matiMD', function (newvValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(oldValue);
        console.log(newvValue);

        });

Comment: where do you define `MetaData` ?